# Check if user exists using mapping in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping

I use solidity to store users information so before that i want to check if the user id already exist or no, Can any one help me with this code ?

i see some solution using array or require all parameters of structure and i don't prefer that, can i do this without these choices?

this function to store user information, if any one have a better code for that, i will appreciate it.

```
contract Contract {

    struct User{
    string fname;
    string Email;
    uint256 age;
    }


    mapping(uint => User)public users; 


 function addDoctor(uint _id, string memory fname, string memory Email,
    uint256 age) public {


         users[_id] = User(fname,email,age);

     }
 }
```

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to add `bool valid` or something similar in `struct User`, otherwise you'll need to use an implicit assumption in order to check whether or not a use exists (for example, `age > 0`).

## UPDATE

Just to be clear, if you want to avoid handling an already-existing user, then you'll need to add:

```
require(!users[_id].valid);
users[_id].valid = true;
```

At the beginning of the function.

Comment: thanks a lot, Can i do that if i want to make a function return bool value ? because i want to use it outside the remix.

Comment: @norah: Since variable `users` is declared `public`, you have at your disposal (implicitly generated by the compiler) `function users(uint key) returns (yourStructFields)`. So if you add a `bool` field to your structure, then you'll be able to get it from Remix by calling that function.

Comment: I use these two functions and it work perfect:     
'function isExist(uint _id) public view returns(bool){
            return users[_id].valid;}
        
function addUser(uint _id, string memory _fname, string memory _email, uint256 _age) public returns(bool) {
       bool q=isExist(_id);
       
       if(q==false){
                users[_id] = user(_fname,email,_age,true);}}' thanks a lot.